# MySQL: GROUP BY and fill empty cells with value from next row from this group

Tags: mysql, group-by

I have a table with products and multiple categories (more than 2), similar to this one:

```
| category1 | category2 |  product  | option |
|  winter   |           |  goodyear |    1   |
|  winter   |           |  goodyear |    2   |
|           |  summer   |  goodyear |    1   |
|           |  summer   |  goodyear |    2   |
```

What I would like to achieve is to GROUP BY 'product' and by 'option', but at the same time fill the empty cells with the content of the next row from this group. The result I am looking to get is:

```
| category1 | category2 |  product  | option | count|
|  winter   |  summer   |  goodyear |    1   |   2  |
|  winter   |  summer   |  goodyear |    2   |   2  |
```

Is it possible to get such result with a MySQL query?

Comment: I don't see a way of doing this with the current table.

Comment: Normalise your schema

Comment: @Strawberry: I agree. Normalizing may mean just to make product + option the primary key here, though. The database design would then be okay for product options having a primary and a secondary category. Both would be in the same record then.

Comment: Normalising would mean having a separate table for categories

Comment: @Strawberry: Let's say product + option were the primary key in above table (so it would be two records instead of four). Which normal form would be violated in your opinion?

Comment: @thorstenkettner by extension, the first one. But I'd be happy to review the myriad examples of enumerated columns (above, sa, '2') in databases that you've created. Not.

Comment: @Strawberry: We don't know what the database is modelling exactly. Maybe free text is fine for what it's supposed to do. I wouldn't demand a table of all existing first names and a table of all existing last names in order to have a users table with first and last name. Of course there can be typos (Jhon instead of John), but maybe it's not important. Maybe typos don't matter in Mike's DB either.

Comment: Tyres. I'm going to go with tyres.

Comment: Haha. Yes. And you are right, the data model is very, very likely inappropriate. It *could* become an okay model with the mentioned primary key, but this seems very unlikely.

Comment: @Strawberry Thank you for the advise! In this case I won't be able to use 2 tables. Typos won't matter, as grouping by product name is my only option here.

Comment: You may think a bit more about Stawberries advice. For the table does look strange, and it somehow seems you are not using the relational database system well. Why can there be even several records for the same product and option? Why is one attribute called category1 and the other category2; does one have precedence over the other? Is this only about tyres? If so, why not have columns is_for_summer, is_for_winter etc. The design doesn't seem to make much sense at first glance. (I still think this is not about normalization, though, but it seems it can be much enhanced still.)

Comment: @ThorstenKettner This is the table I got. Of course it has many more columns, but the main idea is that I need the end result to be in a single table and the products to be grouped by product name and option name in a way, so I can tell in which categories this specific variation of the product appears. The categories have equal priority in this case and your solution suits me perfectly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Isn't this simply:

```
select
  max(category1) as category1,
  max(category2) as category2,
  product,
  option,
  count(*)
from mytable
group by product, option;
```

With an aggregation (`GROUP BY`) you must always specify how to aggregate the other values you are selecting (e.g. whether you want the maximum or the minimum value etc.). Both `MAX` and `MIN` ignore nulls, so you get the value you are interested in.

Comment: Yuk. And you forgot all the other categories :-(

Comment: Thank you, Thorsten! This is exactly the result I was looking for.